# Who can vote in the moderator elections?

Tags: support, election

Are all members able to vote in moderator elections or are there restrictions?

Answer (score 11):

You need [150 reputation to vote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135778/why-is-150-reputation-needed-to-vote-in-elections) on a nominee, and [300 reputation](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/election/2) to nominate yourself.

Comment: Does the 150 include association rep?  I have 178 but 100 of that is by/from association.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald You should be fine.

Comment: @MarkFitzgerald Since association rep is used to unlock privileges, I don't see why there would be an exception for the elections.

Comment: Worst case--post 2-3 answers and you'll have the rep. I got 70 rep yesterday from 2 answers that were my first contribution in a while.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger Well, there *is* an exception that [the association bonus does not count toward the rep needed to answer a protected question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/new-user).